# Getcomponet.var returns null but public var is not null

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine

i have an issue, i have a list of gameobjects getting passed into a function. im getting the gameobject in the list at the Ith position and acsessing a public var of a script placed on the gameobject. the var should return a gameobject but returns null. this is how my code works,

1. script levelMechanics creates a grid of gameobjects with the script nodeMechanics
2. levelMechanics calls the script roomSpawner which tells each node to run there nodeMechanics code, which gets the nodes surrounding nodes and stores them in public vars

both of these steps work great and i can click on each node and in the hierarchy the nodeMechanics script that is attached to each node will tell me the nodes above,below,left and right of the current node. the issue is that if i try to access a nodes surrounding nodes i get null. things ive tried,

1. getting the list in roomSpawner by accessing through levelMechanics instead of levelMechanics putting it into roomSpawner.
2. passing in the list and copying it and the accessing the copied list.
3. both list[i].getcomponet(nodemechanics).nodeDown and list[i].gameobject.getcomponet(nodemechanics).nodeDown
4. getting the nodeMechanics of a node, storing it and then trying to get the data of the stored nodeMechanics instead of just jumping straight into getting the data.

im just lost since the hierarchy is saying that these vars are not null but when i try to access them in code they are. the following code is me trying access the vars

```
  public GameObject test;
  public nodeMechanics temp;

public void IntializeNodes(List<GameObject> nodes)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.Count; i++)
        {
            nodes[i].gameObject.GetComponent<nodeMechanics>().test = true;
//im not sure why i am able to write but not read

        }

    }
    public void SpawnObjects(List<GameObject> nodes)
    {
        //this function is being called in level mechanics and the list is being passed in
        print("nodes created");
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.Count; i++)
        {
            noders.Add(nodes[i]);//the current method is copy over the list and try to access the copy but that doesnt work. i tried not copying
            test = noders[i].gameObject;//ive tried not splint this up and jumping straight into nodes[i]..GetComponent<nodeMechanics>().nodeDown;
            temp = test.GetComponent<nodeMechanics>();
            print(temp.nodeDown);//no matter what i do this always returns null. but in the hierarchy it is not
```

//this is the levelMechanics script

```
   public List<GameObject> objects;
    public List<GameObject> nodes;
    public GameObject floor;
    public float offX, offZ;
    void Awake()
    {
        RoomCheck();
        RoomSetup();
        //GetComponent<roomSpawner>().SpawnEnemys(nodes);
        this.GetComponent<roomSpawner>().IntializeNodes(nodes);
        this.GetComponent<roomSpawner>().SpawnObjects(nodes);


    }
void RoomSetup()
    {
        bool first = true;
        int collCount = -1;
        GameObject placeHolder = new GameObject("temp");
        float colls;

        colls = floor.transform.localScale.x - 1;

        offX = floor.transform.localScale.x;
        offZ = floor.transform.localScale.z;
        offX = (offX / 2) - offX + 1;
        offZ = (offZ / 2) - 1;
        offX = offX + floor.transform.position.x;
        offZ = (offZ + floor.transform.position.z);
        //print(colls);
        for (int i = 0; i < ((floor.transform.localScale.x-1) * (floor.transform.localScale.z-1)); i++)
        {
            collCount++;
            //print(collCount);
            GameObject temp = new GameObject(i + " Node");
            temp.transform.SetParent(floor.transform);
            temp.AddComponent<BoxCollider>();
            temp.GetComponent<BoxCollider>().isTrigger = true;
            temp.AddComponent<nodeMechanics>();
            temp.layer = 9;

            if(!first)
            {
                temp.transform.position = new Vector3((placeHolder.transform.position.x + 1), 6, placeHolder.transform.position.z);
                placeHolder = temp;
                if (collCount >= colls)
                {
                    //print("new line on " + temp.name + " coll " + collCount);
                    collCount = 0;
                    temp.transform.position = new Vector3(floor.transform.localPosition.x + offX, 6, placeHolder.transform.position.z - 1);
                    placeHolder = temp;
                }
            }
            if (first)
            {
                // print(colls);
                temp.transform.position = new Vector3(floor.transform.localPosition.x+offX, 6, floor.transform.localPosition.z+offZ);
                placeHolder = temp;
                first = false;
            }

            nodes.Add(temp);
        }

    }
```

this is the nodeMechanics script

```
public class nodeMechanics : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject nodeUp, nodeDown, nodeLeft, nodeRight, forced;
    public bool test = false;
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (test)
        {
            FindAround();
        }
        if(forced != null)
        {
            Instantiate(forced, this.transform.position, forced.transform.rotation);
        }
    }

    public void FindAround()
    {
        int mask = LayerMask.GetMask("Node");
        RaycastHit up, down, left, right;
        if (Physics.Raycast(this.transform.position, Vector3.forward, out up, 1, mask))
        {
            nodeUp = up.collider.transform.gameObject;
        }
        if (Physics.Raycast(this.transform.position, Vector3.back, out down, 1, mask))
        {
            nodeDown = down.collider.transform.gameObject;
        }
        if (Physics.Raycast(this.transform.position, Vector3.left, out left, 1, mask))
        {
            nodeLeft = left.collider.transform.gameObject;
        }
        if (Physics.Raycast(this.transform.position, Vector3.right, out right, 1, mask))
        {
            nodeRight = right.collider.transform.gameObject;
        }
    }
}
```

to clarify the following code is not working properly

```
 for (int i = 0; i < nodes.Count; i++)
        {
            noders.Add(nodes[i]);//the current method is copy over the list and try to access the copy but that doesnt work. i tried not copying
            test = noders[i].gameObject;//ive tried not splint this up and jumping straight into nodes[i]..GetComponent<nodeMechanics>().nodeDown;
            temp = test.GetComponent<nodeMechanics>();
            print(temp.nodeDown);
```

temp.nodeDown should return the correct node but returns null, in the hierarchy it shows the correct object and not null

Comment: That is a lot of text and code for me to read without more explicit guidance as to which line of code is having the issue.

Comment: sure, i edited for ya

Comment: What happens if you use `var bob` rather than `temp` (and then use `bob.nodeDown` on the next line)? Does that work?

Comment: still returns null

Comment: just added public the function          GameObject getDown()
    {
        return nodeDown;
    }  to node mechanics and called it from where im trying to print out nodeDown but im still getting null

Comment: solved, since i was calling the spawnRoom right after the intializeNodes i guess unity ran them ontop of each other.

Answer (score 0):

solved, since i was calling the spawnRoom right after the intializeNodes i guess unity ran them ontop of each other